# `e.getModifierState is not a function` error on triggered keyup event

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, keyevent, keyup, dispatchevent

I am trying to detect whether the client has their CapsLock enabled by temporarily creating a hidden input field, triggering a `keyup` event on that input, and then checking the boolean value of `e.getModifierState('CapsLock')`.

The function I've written is below, which currently throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: e.getModifierState is not a function` on the line which includes `e.getModifierState` and I'm struggling to diagnose why this is occurring. I'm open to any help here!

```js
let checkCaps = () => {
    let tempInput = document.createElement('input');
    let keyupEvent = new Event('keyup');
    tempInput.type = 'hidden';
    tempInput.id = 'check-caps';
    let capsOn = false;
    tempInput.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
        e.which = 65;
        capsOn = e.getModifierState('CapsLock');
    })
    tempInput.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent);
    tempInput.remove();
    return capsOn;
}

checkCaps(); // testing the function
```

Comment: You haven't specified the type for the dispatched event, create a `KeyboardEvent` instead of `Event`.

Answer (score 1):

The class `Event` is the base class for all specific event classes.
If you want to generate a keyboard event, then you must use the `KeyboardEvent` class like this:

```
    let checkCaps = () => {
    let tempInput = document.createElement('input');
    let keyupEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keyup');
    tempInput.type = 'hidden';
    tempInput.id = 'check-caps';
    let capsOn = false;
    tempInput.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
        e.which = 65;
        capsOn = e.getModifierState('CapsLock');
    })
    tempInput.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent);
    tempInput.remove();
    return capsOn;
}

checkCaps(); // testing the function
```

If tested this and the code runs, but I always get `false` for `getModifierState('CapsLock')`

It seems that for you must specify the current value self-generated KeyboardEvents. But this isn't what you want.
It seems that other people had the same issue and there is no solution without real user input.

See: [How to detect Caps Lock state on page load (that is, not on keypress) with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792106/how-to-detect-caps-lock-state-on-page-load-that-is-not-on-keypress-with-javas)